# Can't see named routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm sure i'm doing something stupid, but i just can't get this to work.
I defined routes in a separate js file, imported that into a newly created router, that i mounted in vue.
In the vue devtools i do see my named routes, but where the RouterView is in the vue devtools, the html shows

Routes.js:

```
import Home from '@/Views/Home.vue';
import NewProefwerk from '@/Views/NewProefwerk.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        Component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/Nieuw',
        name: 'new',
        Component: NewProefwerk
    }
];

export default routes;
```

main.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from '@/Routes'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/',
    routes
})

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navigation></Navigation>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            Navigation
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `Component` to `component`.